# Iptables working without configuration

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, redhat

I am currently going to port a Red Hat 6.4 machine and I need its firewall configuration, but something is going on.

`iptables -L` shows a list of rules as expected, but at the same time I can't find my `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` (or `/etc/sysconfig/ip6tables`). That's the first question I have: where is it getting the rules from? There is no special script on `/etc/rcX.d/` directory.

Since the firewall is running I wanted to check it with the GUI tool through `system-configuration-firewall`, but it states the firewall is `disabled`. That's the second question: how is it running but disabled at the same time?

I know I can clone the disk to port the machine but I just wanted to check some files prior to that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not everyone starts their firewalls up using the system-provided pathways.  What does `grep iptables /etc/rc3.d/*` give?

Comment: It shows the contents of the file S08iptables, in charge of starting the firewall, which I knew it was there. But since this script is trying to load the iptables file and it doesn't exist I guessed it had to be a different script, which is missing.

Comment: It's possible those rules were loaded manually, and don't automatically come from *anywhere*.  Have you rebooted the machine to make sure they come back?

Comment: Yes, the machine has already been rebooted several times prior to this week. The firewall is apparently working just fine.

Comment: I hear you, but that's not quite what I asked.  It's possible that the firewall startup script has been amended or removed since the last reboot; if you want to be *sure* that you're not hunting a ghost, you need to reboot the machine and then immediately afterwards look for it.

Comment: After rebooting the behaviour is the same. Same rules but no rules file whatsoever. I also checked that `IPTABLES_SAVE_ON_RESTART="no"` is in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config`, which I believe would store the current rules so it has to load them from somewhere else.

Comment: Fair enough.  Time to widen the net; try `find /etc -type f -exec grep iptables {} /dev/null \;`.

Comment: It shows a bunch of files from `/etc/selinux`, the script `/etc/rc.d/init.d/iptables`, the file `/etc/sysctl.conf` (and `/etc/sysctl.confe` for some reason) and `/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config`. I can see that in `/etc/rc.d/init.d/iptables` the variable `IPTABLES` is set to `iptables` and afterwards it states the rules are in that file and even it states that if the file is missing the service shall not be started. Inside `/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config` I see no rules, just variables.

Comment: It's possible that the script that sets the rules does not itself contain the word `iptables` - it may use a variable passed in from elsewhere.  Is there anything in the running ruleset, such as a site-specific address range, that you could search for and turn up less false positives?

Comment: It is still looking for a rule with a specific IP (the only specific thing I can think of), but I guess I'll just clone the machine. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that there is actual script which is ran after restart? Do you have iptables rules after restart of this PC?

Comment: Yes, I have rules and the firewall is running, but they are not coming from the iptables file since `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` is still missing.

Comment: Do they persist after restart of this PC? You can add rules dinamically to firewall with "iptables" command-line utility. Scripts are required to have this rules after restart of PC.

Answer (score 0):

Check your /etc/rc.local file. However in red hat there should be /etc/init.d/iptables script which is loading rules from /etc/sysconfig/iptables-save file

Comment: /etc/rc.local shows the following line: "touch /var/lock/subsys/local". And the file /etc/sysconfig/iptables-save is missing, also I thought it was a script to dump the rules, which is what it does indeed, but I don't know where the rules are stored.